# Any debris-tolerant toilet fill valves?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, uk

Are there any modern toilet fill valves that can tolerate small debris in the water supply?

My old toilet cistern re-filled itself with a [traditional ball-cock](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxZvBaviK-VNywU7pAHSWcMvTtMwHs_N3yk6I_GVv9w2cTcCxnk-AXN5enmwaiyWZFk6Wj5vN48-iJvHzh5o66rNe4fCf53lEs7wp5PR7WN444Gxk2d4GllLsQCahUFnBOyOHOlD9rMg&usqp=CAc) valve. My new slimline, low-profile toilet cistern uses a vertical toilet-fill valve. Like [this](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcRmVGX_yh7X-9Tib85-SfCsLxCDgaQvyhUBbn6cw1yT87yTu21Dyfl2GT6guoPcIzqSNXHCsuaiag3aEdlj8FlZHg5lm_fqAR6AI816k5QaDTkJBoEfWCIlCYD5C4UK7-CJkMh6lw&usqp=CAc) one.

The old one has a valve nozzle a few millimetres across, this could easily cope with the occasional random bit of debris in the water supply. The new one is designed to be small and compact (to fit the slimline cistern) the drawback is that the mechanism relies on control holes a fraction of a millimetre across (see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twynH8xVdy8&ab_channel=HacksbyDad) for details).

The water comes from a stream in the garden. Water for drinking gets properly filtered and treated, but water for bathing and toilets goes through a gravel bed for basic filtering, occasional bits of grit get through the filter beds and clog the fill valves, so I'm looking a valve that works like an old ball-cock valve, but is small enough fit in a slimline cistern.

Answer (score 7):

These [Sediment filters](https://www.freshwatersystems.com/products/vu-flow-sediment-screen-filter-t-style-1-5?variant=13249387790379&c1=GAW_SE_NW&source=PLA_USA_PM_FILTCART&cr2=pmax__-__nw__-__replacement_filters_AMP_cartridges&kw=13249387790379&cr5=pla&cr7=c&utm_term=13249387790379&utm_campaign=pmax__-__nw__-__replacement_filters_AMP_cartridges&utm_source=PLA_USA_PM_FILTCART&utm_medium=cpc&hsa_acc=2014103020&hsa_cam=11853986621&hsa_grp=&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAgeeqBhBAEiwAoDDhnzxAvTZKZ03fHTV4zl9faCKK3ChPxZgeeVYLfVIQ55lWmU8NRohXUxoCIN0QAvD_BwE) are designed for what you need to filter the water.

If the smaller screen clogs quickly, you can replace the screen with something larger.  They are easy to clean by just opening the valve.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for a tolerant float valve you could add a strainer after the graver bed to catch the grit before it gets to the fill valve.

Essentially putting in holes t§o clog in a spot where you can easily get at them to unclog.